# Creating a loop statement to recieve a value based on a letter

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, return-value, letter

Is it recommended to use a for-each loop statement that will print out certain values (things) based on their first letter? For example "A" = Apple, Airplane. Can a continue statement be used?

```
package class_inClass0920a;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declare an array of strings
        String[] things;
        things = new String[] {"Apple", "Airplane", "Car", "Football","House", "Aluminum"};

        for (int i=0; i < things.length; i++) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to handle this:

```
public class Running {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare an array of strings
    String[] things;
    things = new String[] { "Apple", "Airplane", "Car", "Football",
            "House", "Aluminum" };

    for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
        if(things[i].startsWith("A")) {
            System.out.println(things[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
Apple
Airplane
Aluminum
```

You can easily handle different conditions using this technique.